# How to save file by StreamWriter with special signs

Tags: c#, string, file

I have a following simple code:

```
File.Copy("in.txt", "elem.txt", true);
    string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("temp.txt");
    StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter("in.txt", false);
    sw.Flush();
    foreach (string line in lines)
    {
        if (line.Contains("obcy"))
        {
           line.Remove(0);
           continue;
        }
    sw.WriteLine(line);                
    }
```

First string:

> Temat,Lokalizacja,Data rozpoczęcia,Czas rozpoczęcia

Line removing is working correct only this characters work bad.

My temp file contains special characters like "ę" or "ń" and when I write this to in.txt file, I have following result:

> Temat,Lokalizacja,Data rozpocz�cia,Czas rozpocz�cia

What to do with this problem any ideas?

Comment: Can you give example of initial text to try to reproduce it ?

Comment: Both File.ReadAllLines and the StreamWriter's constructor accept an encoding. I'm guessing yours is UTF-8.

Comment: Notepad doesn't support your encoding. Open it in notepad++. Issue is not with your code. Its your text viewer

Comment: The problem is encoding. Probably, 'temp.txt` has `Windows cp-1250` encoding. If so, pass encoding to `ReadAllLines` as second parameter (see overloads).

Comment: I have ANSI encoding in both files.

Comment: But as others have been trying to explain, .NET is writing a UTF8 file. Notepad (or whatever you're using to look at the output) only _thinks_ the file is using ANSI encoding. But it's not, and so it has unrecognized characters in it. You need to use an editor that will treat the output file correctly.

Comment: @Sowiarz ANSI encoding is a slightly generic term used to refer to the standard code page on a system. In your case I suppose is mentioned Windows cp-1250 (for polish windows). Stream writes / reads file in UTF-8, so the problem occurs.

Comment: @pwas thanks I passed encoding to "ReadAllLines" and now its working thanks!

Comment: you are changing the collection in foreach ,why is it working here ,anybody can kindly explain ? or it just give error for insert and delete

Comment: Do not put "[Completed]" in the tile of your post. Mark your own answer as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 1):

"The problem is encoding. Probably, 'temp.txt` has Windows cp-1250 encoding. If so, pass encoding to ReadAllLines as second parameter (see overloads)." @pwas

I added following changes to code:

`string[] lines = File.ReadAllLines("elem.txt", Encoding.GetEncoding("Windows-1250"));`

Thanks man!